# Is there a way to create an installer or .exe that perform all the linux commands with just one clicks?

Tags: linux

I have multiple linux commands and within each command there is a need to change a file configuration.
I am wondering whether is there a way to compile everything and let it run in a stack after a click?

Example,

```
1) install requirements.txt
2) mv fileA.txt /home/user
3) pip install dictionary
4) mv fileB.txt /home/user
5) --another special command specifically for the dictionary like fasttext--
6) more commands
```

then complete.

Is there a way to compile all linux commands such as above?

Comment: Why don't you create a Shell script? You won't be able to run .exe file on Linux as this is a different platform and .exe does not mean anything to Linux

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek Maybe the user wants to include the files to be installed in the installer executable. Just like in a "self-extracting" ZIP file.

Comment: Hi sir Sebastian, thank you but do you think you could share me some details or links related to this? I tried to search but could not find the relevant one.

Comment: hi martin, But there are some include the running of linux commands. Is it possible to use it this way?